# Subscribing to Docker Events

Tags: events, docker

This might be a dumb question and more related to shell scripting however. How do subscribe to a 'die' event and capture the container name. I've got this which sort of works

```
docker events --filter 'event=die' | while read event
do
    echo event
done
```

However, its doesn't output anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this seems to work, unless there's a better way to do this.

```
while IFS= read -r result
do  
    echo $result
done < <(docker events --filter 'event=die')
```

Comment: dont we have anything that is out of box to subscribe to docker event. like if I want to send a mail when status changed to Die